# Prototype/Javascript DOM-Element ID as parameter

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I want to hand over an id to a Javascript function as a parameter (inRef) and then process it with the protoype Fade.Effect.
My function looks as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fadeEffect(inRef) {
        $(inRef).fade({ duration: 1.8, from: 0.7, to: 1 });
    } 
</script>
```

Firefox and Opera can handle it correctly, whereas Chrome and Safari throw a console error saying inRef is undefined.
I hand over the inRef as a string and think Javascript needs it as something else (JSON?)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what is the value that you are passing to `inref`?

Comment: The value is already undefined. So I have to typecast it before?! But as what?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function alert(typeof inRef) to check whether inRef is cast as a string in webkit browsers.

```
function fadeEffect(inRef) {
        alert(typeof inRef);
        $(inRef).fade({ duration: 1.8, from: 0.7, to: 1 });
}
```

If its not, cast it as a string

```
function fadeEffect(inRef) {
        $(inRef.toString()).fade({ duration: 1.8, from: 0.7, to: 1 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inRef can be a string since $(inRef) turns it into an object reference. Perhaps the problem lies somewhere else. What happens if you use the literal instead of the variable?

```
$("divname").fade({ duration: 1.8, from: 0.7, to: 1 });
```